# Transportando dados entre AppDelegate e ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Meu problema é o seguinte. Preciso que quando o usuário inicie meu App, ele volte com os dados que estava na tela antes de fecha-lo.
Então minha ideia inicial, é quando o app entrar em Background ele grave um Plist com as informações que estavam na tela e quando for iniciado novamente ele carrega essa Plist e envia para o ViewController onde se encontra essas informações...

Mas como faço para passar a informação carregada na AppDelegate para a minha ViewController?

PS: Sintam-se a vontade para questionar minha solução e/ou dar uma solução mais plausível para o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa salvar essa informação no AppDelegate. Em geral aconselho não colocar a lógica da aplicação nessa classe e sim tentar separar em módulos.
Uma sugestão seria repassar a notificação do AppDelegate para o ViewController, ou melhor ainda, diretamente escutar pela notificação no seu ViewController. Para tanto, adicione um observer no método `-viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(enteredBackground:) 
    name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
    object:nil];
```

O método `- (void)enteredBackground:(NSNotification *)notification` será chamado a cada vez que aplicação entrar em background e lá você coloca o código pra salvar a informação no plist. Não esqueça de remover o observer no método -dealloc.
Você também pode considerar outras formas de armazenar a informação, como: CoreData, sqlite, user defaults. Pra escolher a melhor é necessário analisar os requisitos da aplicação.

Comment: São apenas duas informações, uma NSString e um NSNumber... no caso de buscar essas informações salvas quando o app é iniciado eu usei `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification`... é isso certo?

Comment: O ARC não controla essa remoção do observer? Ou preciso mesmo remover no `-dealloc`?

Comment: Se são apenas dois atributos, salvar no NSUserDefaults é forma mais simples e rápida. Creio que não seja necessário realizar a leitura dos valores no AppDelegate. Você pode fazer isso no -viewDidLoad do ViewController, pois caso a app seja fechada, o ViewController será criado quando da nova execução.

Comment: Quanto a remoção do observer, em geral não é necessário fazer manualmente. Depende de quando no ciclo de vida do VC ele foi adicionado. Por exemplo, se adicionar no `-viewWillAppear`, o certo é remover no `-viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 2):

Ja existe uma solução pronta no próprio iOS para este problema chamada [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

E aqui um bom tutorial sobre o assunto: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

É uma leitura longa com uma curva de aprendizado um pouco maior, porém é a melhor solução para este tipo de problema. Vale a pena!

Answer (score 2):

Eu tenho usado o NSUserdefaults e ele dá conta bem disso.

Para gravar:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setInteger:1234 forKey:@"senha"];
[ud synchronize];
```

para ler:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger SenhaUsuario = [ud integerForKey:@"senha"];
```

Não esqueça de sincronizar quando fizer atualizações nos dados.